# PHP function gives Server error 500

Tags: php, oop, pdo

So i wrote a small search function, but when i include it into my class my site brakes and gives me an Server Error 500.
I am new to OOP & PDO, so i am not sure if i did a general mistake or it`s just a typo somewhere. I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

My function:

```
<?php
public function searchFullTextPanel($q)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT id,firstname,lastname,adresse_str,adresse_plz,adresse_ort,adresse_land,telefon,email,image_name FROM partner WHERE MATCH (firstname,lastname,adresse_str,adresse_plz,adresse_ort,adresse_land,telefon,email) AGAINST q=:q ");

        $stmt->bindparam(":q",$q);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                    <td><img src="../cv-imgs/<?php print($row['image_name']); ?>" height="42" width="42"></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['firstname']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['lastname']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['email']); ?></td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <form  name="editPartner" method="post" action="anlegen.php"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><button type="submit" name="editPartner"><i style="color: orange" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button></form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form  name="delPartner" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><button type="submit" name="delPartner"><i style="color: red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></button></form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>fml...</td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And i call it like this in my site:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {   
        $q = $_POST['q'];
        $crud->searchFullTextPanel($q);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Set PHP to display errors. 
With some configurations, no errors are shown, only a 500 error.

Comment: Set `display_errors` to `On` and `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` (for development purpose only) in the php.ini. If `display_errors` is on `Off` then a HTTP 500 will be dispatched. On a try-block there has to be a catch-block to catch an exception, otherwise `try` wouldn't make any sense. Catch the `PDOException` `try { ... } catch(PDOException $e) { ... }`.

Comment: Tyvm, yes it was the try-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that you dont close your try block with a catch block. But there could also be something else, please check your error logs on the server.

Comment: Tyvm, yes i fixed it, that was part of the problem.